# Not able to connect to AWS documentdb using GoLang

Tags: mongodb, go, aws-documentdb

I am able to connect to AWS docdb using the same ec2 via mongo compass, but not with golang.

However when I tried connecting using golang mongo-driver.
I have opened a ssh tunnel using the following command

`ssh -i "key.pem" -L 28100:endpoint.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 ec2-user@111.111.111.111.region.compute.amazonaws.com`

My connection uri is

`mongodb://user:password@localhost:28100/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=secrets/global-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false&directConnection=true`

I encounter an error when I tried to ping to the docdb

```
client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), options.Client().ApplyURI(tempURI).SetTLSConfig(tlsConfig))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), connectTimeout*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)
```

Error

`server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers:  [{ Addr: localhost:28100, Type: Unknown, Last error: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for endpoint.docdb.amazonaws.com, not localhost }, ] }`

Answer (score 0):

Because you're connecting to localhost, you need to add `sslAllowInvalidHostnames`  to your connection uri.